# Why start command works without path for some files?

Tags: windows-7, command-line

When I try to start a program with `start` command without specifying path, for some programs it works and for some programs it doesn't work.

I know that if those programs are in my PATH list or in current directory, I don't have to type the path.

But `start` command works for some programs even if those aren't in current directory or in my PATH list. What is the reason for this?

Comment: [Related](http://superuser.com/a/494548/117590) (actually, close to a duplicate...)

Comment: @Bob, you're right. It's close to a duplicate, but I couldn't find it. The title means something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It searches the [App Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121(v=vs.85).aspx) registry key.

> #### [Finding an Application Executable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121(v=vs.85).aspx#app_exe)
>
> When the [ShellExecuteEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154(v=vs.85).aspx) function is called with the name of an executable file in its *lpFile* parameter, there are several places where the function looks for the file. We recommend registering your application in the **`App Paths`** registry subkey. Doing so avoids the need for applications to modify the system `PATH` environment variable.
>
> The file is sought in the following locations:
>
> - The current working directory.
> - The **`Windows`** directory only (no subdirectories are searched).
> - The **`Windows\System32`** directory.
> - Directories listed in the `PATH` environment variable.
> - Recommended: **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths`**

Comment: what is ShellExecuteEx function?