# Windows: Can't launch any program from command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables

I need to have ability to start program by the file name on Windows 7 like firefox.exe.
But nothing from [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/494538/how-do-i-open-a-program-via-the-command-prompt-in-windows-8) works. ie Notepad++ creates an entry in App Paths but still command prompt is unable to launch it.

For sake of testing, I copied notepad++.exe in System32 and then it could start from command line.

So it would seem that Windows/command line ignores/fails to see the PATH enviromental variable and App Paths registry.

PATH entries:

> C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\SnapAPI\; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\; C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\

Registry App path:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths]
"Path"="C:\\Program Files\\IDT\\"
@="C:\\Program Files\\IDT\\"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\AcroRd32.exe]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Acrobat Reader DC\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe"
"Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Acrobat Reader DC\\Reader\\"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\acs.exe]
@="C:\\Program Files\\Agnitum\\Outpost Security Suite Pro\\acs.exe"
"Path"="C:\\Program Files\\Agnitum\\Outpost Security Suite Pro"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\cmmgr32.exe]
"CmstpExtensionDll"="C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmcfg32.dll"
"CmNative"=dword:00000002

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\CyberLink Media Suite10]
"Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\CyberLink\\Media Suite"
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\CyberLink\\Media Suite\\PS.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\devenv.exe]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\Common7\\IDE\\devenv.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\dexplore.exe]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\Help 8\\dexplore.exe\""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\dvdmaker.exe]
@=hex(2):25,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,\
  00,73,00,25,00,5c,00,44,00,56,00,44,00,20,00,4d,00,61,00,6b,00,65,00,72,00,\
  5c,00,64,00,76,00,64,00,6d,00,61,00,6b,00,65,00,72,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,\
  00,00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\ENScript.exe]
"Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Evernote\\Evernote\\"
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Evernote\\Evernote\\ENScript.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Evernote.exe]
"Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Evernote\\Evernote\\"
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Evernote\\Evernote\\Evernote.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\EvernoteClipper.exe]
"Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Evernote\\Evernote\\"
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Evernote\\Evernote\\EvernoteClipper.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\excel.exe]
@="C:\\PROGRA~2\\MICROS~1\\Office12\\EXCEL.EXE"
"Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\"
"SaveURL"="1"
"useURL"="1"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\ExtraChm.exe]
"Path"=""
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ExtraToolBox\\ExtraChm\\ExtraChm.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\firefox.exe]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"
"Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\GROOVE.EXE]
@="C:\\PROGRA~2\\MICROS~1\\Office12\\GROOVE.EXE"
"Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\"
"useURL"="1"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\IEDIAG.EXE]
@="C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\IEDIAGCMD.EXE"
"Path"="C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer;"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\IEDIAGCMD.EXE]
@="C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\IEDIAGCMD.EXE"
"Path"="C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer;"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\IEXPLORE.EXE]
@="C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\IEXPLORE.EXE"
"Path"="C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer;"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\IEXPLORE.EXE\SupportedProtocols]
"https"=""
"about"=""
"mhtml"=""
"mk"=""
"file"=""
"ftp"=""
"res"=""
"local"=""
"http"=""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\infopath.exe]
@="C:\\PROGRA~2\\MICROS~1\\Office12\\INFOPATH.EXE"
"Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\"
"useURL"="1"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\install.exe]
"BlockOnTSNonInstallMode"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\javaws.exe]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre1.8.0_65\\bin\\javaws.exe"
"Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre1.8.0_65\\bin"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Journal.exe]
@=hex(2):25,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,\
  00,73,00,25,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,6f,00,77,00,73,00,20,00,4a,00,\
  6f,00,75,00,72,00,6e,00,61,00,6c,00,5c,00,4a,00,6f,00,75,00,72,00,6e,00,61,\
  00,6c,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\LyX.exe]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\LyX 2.1\\bin\\lyx.exe"
"OnlyWithLyX"="Yes213"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\matlab.exe]
@="C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2015a\\bin\\matlab.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\mfbclient.exe]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\Common7\\IDE\\mfbclient.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\mip.exe]
@=hex(2):25,00,43,00,6f,00,6d,00,6d,00,6f,00,6e,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,\
  00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,25,00,5c,00,4d,00,69,00,63,00,\
  72,00,6f,00,73,00,6f,00,66,00,74,00,20,00,53,00,68,00,61,00,72,00,65,00,64,\
  00,5c,00,49,00,6e,00,6b,00,5c,00,6d,00,69,00,70,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,\
  00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\mpc-hc.exe]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\K-Lite Codec Pack\\MPC-HC\\mpc-hc.exe"
"Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\K-Lite Codec Pack\\MPC-HC"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\mpc-hc64.exe]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\K-Lite Codec Pack\\MPC-HC64\\mpc-hc64.exe"
"Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\K-Lite Codec Pack\\MPC-HC64"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\mplayer2.exe]
@=hex(2):25,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,\
  00,73,00,28,00,78,00,38,00,36,00,29,00,25,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,\
  6f,00,77,00,73,00,20,00,4d,00,65,00,64,00,69,00,61,00,20,00,50,00,6c,00,61,\
  00,79,00,65,00,72,00,5c,00,77,00,6d,00,70,00,6c,00,61,00,79,00,65,00,72,00,\
  2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,00,00
"Path"=hex(2):25,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,69,00,6c,\
  00,65,00,73,00,28,00,78,00,38,00,36,00,29,00,25,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,\
  64,00,6f,00,77,00,73,00,20,00,4d,00,65,00,64,00,69,00,61,00,20,00,50,00,6c,\
  00,61,00,79,00,65,00,72,00,00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\MSACCESS.EXE]
@="C:\\PROGRA~2\\MICROS~1\\Office12\\MSACCESS.EXE"
"Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\"
"useURL"="1"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\MsoHtmEd.exe]
"useURL"="1"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\msoxmled.exe]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\OFFICE14\\MSOXMLED.EXE"
"useURL"="1"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\MSPUB.EXE]
@="C:\\PROGRA~2\\MICROS~1\\Office12\\MSPUB.EXE"
"Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\"
"useURL"=dword:00000001
"SaveURL"="1"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\mtm.exe]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\Common7\\IDE\\mtm.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\notepad++.exe]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\ois.exe]
@="C:\\PROGRA~2\\MICROS~1\\Office14\\OIS.EXE"
"Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\"
"SaveURL"="0"
"useURL"="1"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\OneNote.exe]
@="C:\\PROGRA~2\\MICROS~1\\Office12\\ONENOTE.EXE"
"Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\"
"SaveURL"="1"
"useURL"="1"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\OUTLOOK.EXE]
@="C:\\PROGRA~2\\MICROS~1\\Office12\\OUTLOOK.EXE"
"Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\pbrush.exe]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,6d,00,73,00,\
  70,00,61,00,69,00,6e,00,74,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,00,00
"Path"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,\
  00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Power2Go8]
"Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\CyberLink\\Power2Go8"
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\CyberLink\\Power2Go8\\Power2Go8.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Power2GoExpress8.exe]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\CyberLink\\Power2Go8\\Power2GoExpress8.exe\""
"path"="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\CyberLink\\Power2Go8\""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\PowerDirector10]
"Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\CyberLink\\PowerDirector10"
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\CyberLink\\PowerDirector10\\PDR10.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\powerpnt.exe]
@="C:\\PROGRA~2\\MICROS~1\\Office12\\POWERPNT.EXE"
"Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\"
"useURL"="1"
"SaveURL"="1"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\PowerShell.exe]
@="%SystemRoot%\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\PowerShell.exe"
"Path"="%SystemRoot%\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\PowerStarter]
"Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\CyberLink\\Media Suite"
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\CyberLink\\Media Suite\\PS.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\setup.exe]
"BlockOnTSNonInstallMode"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\sidebar.exe]
@=hex(2):22,00,25,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,69,00,6c,\
  00,65,00,73,00,25,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,6f,00,77,00,73,00,20,00,\
  53,00,69,00,64,00,65,00,62,00,61,00,72,00,5c,00,73,00,69,00,64,00,65,00,62,\
  00,61,00,72,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\SnippingTool.exe]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,53,00,6e,00,\
  69,00,70,00,70,00,69,00,6e,00,67,00,54,00,6f,00,6f,00,6c,00,2e,00,65,00,78,\
  00,65,00,00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\SoftPaqDownloadManager.exe]
@="C:\\PROGRA~2\\HEWLET~1\\HPSOFT~2\\SOFTPA~1.EXE"
"Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Hewlett-Packard\\HP SoftPaq Download Manager\\"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\SopCast.exe]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SopCast\\SopCast.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\table30.exe]
"UseShortName"=""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\TabTip.exe]
@=hex(2):25,00,43,00,6f,00,6d,00,6d,00,6f,00,6e,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,\
  00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,25,00,5c,00,6d,00,69,00,63,00,\
  72,00,6f,00,73,00,6f,00,66,00,74,00,20,00,73,00,68,00,61,00,72,00,65,00,64,\
  00,5c,00,69,00,6e,00,6b,00,5c,00,54,00,61,00,62,00,54,00,69,00,70,00,2e,00,\
  65,00,78,00,65,00,00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\visio.exe]
@="C:\\PROGRA~2\\MICROS~1\\Office14\\VISIO.EXE"
"Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\"
"useURL"="1"
"SaveURL"="1"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\vsta.exe]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\\Common7\\IDE\\vsta.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\vstoee.dll]
"UseURL"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\wab.exe]
@=hex(2):25,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,\
  00,73,00,25,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,6f,00,77,00,73,00,20,00,4d,00,\
  61,00,69,00,6c,00,5c,00,77,00,61,00,62,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,00,00
"Path"=hex(2):25,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,69,00,6c,\
  00,65,00,73,00,25,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,6f,00,77,00,73,00,20,00,\
  4d,00,61,00,69,00,6c,00,00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\wabmig.exe]
@=hex(2):25,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,\
  00,73,00,25,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,6f,00,77,00,73,00,20,00,4d,00,\
  61,00,69,00,6c,00,5c,00,77,00,61,00,62,00,6d,00,69,00,67,00,2e,00,65,00,78,\
  00,65,00,00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\WinRAR.exe]
@="C:\\Program Files\\WinRAR\\WinRAR.exe"
"Path"="C:\\Program Files\\WinRAR"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Winword.exe]
@="C:\\PROGRA~2\\MICROS~1\\Office12\\WINWORD.EXE"
"Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\"
"useURL"="1"
"SaveURL"="1"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\wmplayer.exe]
@=hex(2):25,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,\
  00,73,00,28,00,78,00,38,00,36,00,29,00,25,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,\
  6f,00,77,00,73,00,20,00,4d,00,65,00,64,00,69,00,61,00,20,00,50,00,6c,00,61,\
  00,79,00,65,00,72,00,5c,00,77,00,6d,00,70,00,6c,00,61,00,79,00,65,00,72,00,\
  2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,00,00
"Path"=hex(2):25,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,69,00,6c,\
  00,65,00,73,00,28,00,78,00,38,00,36,00,29,00,25,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,\
  64,00,6f,00,77,00,73,00,20,00,4d,00,65,00,64,00,69,00,61,00,20,00,50,00,6c,\
  00,61,00,79,00,65,00,72,00,00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\WORDPAD.EXE]
@=hex(2):22,00,25,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,69,00,6c,\
  00,65,00,73,00,25,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,6f,00,77,00,73,00,20,00,\
  4e,00,54,00,5c,00,41,00,63,00,63,00,65,00,73,00,73,00,6f,00,72,00,69,00,65,\
  00,73,00,5c,00,57,00,4f,00,52,00,44,00,50,00,41,00,44,00,2e,00,45,00,58,00,\
  45,00,22,00,00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\WRITE.EXE]
@=hex(2):22,00,25,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,69,00,6c,\
  00,65,00,73,00,25,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,6f,00,77,00,73,00,20,00,\
  4e,00,54,00,5c,00,41,00,63,00,63,00,65,00,73,00,73,00,6f,00,72,00,69,00,65,\
  00,73,00,5c,00,57,00,4f,00,52,00,44,00,50,00,41,00,44,00,2e,00,45,00,58,00,\
  45,00,22,00,00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\YouCam]
"Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\CyberLink\\YouCam"
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\CyberLink\\YouCam\\YouCam.exe"
```

Comment: Excuse me, but have you bothered to read the question or just marked after seeing the title? I specifically mentioned that that thread doesn't help. Please remove the duplicate marking

Comment: Notepad++ work perfectly well if you add it to the path. If you think the other question isn't a duplicate please [edit] your question and say why. Tell us exactly what didn't work.

Comment: You have provided no diagnostic information, for example what is in your PATH, and your registry App Paths.

Comment: Please also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Exactly,  it should, but it doesn't, neither Firefox, neither anything else. I thought i made it clear.
I have no idea what is needed. I will add PATH list shortly, but nit sure how to post registry App Paths. it's a long list

Comment: So it turns out the duplicate is a duplicate (yes, I did bother to read your question). 1/ You had a mistake in your path (the extra space) and 2/ You were not calling start notepad++. I can't close it as duplicate again because I reopened it for you.

Comment: once more: 1. I wanted to launch it without start. I omitted the background as irrelevant. Which is if you can start something from command promt, then other application can do it too. In my case Xilinx Vivado starting notepad++ as external editor.
2. Because of _accepted_ answer in the thread (now edited), you beleive this thread duplicates, I assumed, that that should be possible if a programm has an entry in App Paths

Comment: that way this thread has helped to sort out 3-years old mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space before `C:\` from the last entry in the PATH `; C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\`.

The above should fix the Notepad++ issue. For other programs, post their exact location, and the related entries in the PATH or App Paths.

---

[ EDIT ] When starting programs that are registered under App Paths (but not in the PATH environment variable) one must explicitly use `start`.

For example, just `notepad++` will give a `not recognized` error at the cmd prompt, but `start "" "notepad++"` (or simply `start notepad++` if the name contains no spaces or other special characters) will run the .exe from the location in App Paths.

Comment: Yes that helped thanks. But that shouldn't have been neccessary  because notepad++ has entry in app path.
exported app path subtree and added to the first post. These entries were created by installers and the paths of the application correspond to respective entries, so actually there is no good reason they wouldn't work.

Comment: @AndreyPro I guess you are not using `start` , see my edit. This is why it helps to provide all relevant details upfront.

Comment: I mentioned in the post, that i would like to start simply by name.
And also the answer in the linked post tells that no start needed fo app path

Comment: You said `start program by the file name`. The answer is `start notepad++`. You also said that nothing from the linked thread worked for you, yet the question itself being asked there was `have tried the command line START any_program.exe, but ...`. Anyway, I take it that you've got it working now. All is well which ends well, only it tends to end sooner the more complete the question is to begin with.

Comment: @AndreyPro P.S. You have a point that the accepted answer to the other question does not make the distinction between `start` and direct execution at the cmd prompt. I just posted a comment there to clarify, not that I think many will read it 3 years after the fact.