# Is this ok to install python on d drive?

Tags: python

I am using window 10 and want to install python on d drive because after reinstalling Windows, I don't want to reinstall python again and don't want to take backup of python before reinstalling Windows

Is this ok to install python on d drive?

Comment: You can install python wherever you like ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - however you nedd to be careful with your `path` variable. You can tell the installer to automatically add `python` to the `path` variable while installing, when reinstalling windows you will have to set it manually.
[How do I add Python to the Windows PATH?](https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-windows-path)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible. 
Note the path in which the python binary file exists.

I installed mine in D drive. 
[Python binary file under D:\Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDL8Q.png)

Now type sysdm.cpl in Run window. And the System Properties window opens up. Open Advanced tab and select Environment Variables.

In the System variable section, select "Path" and give Edit option.

Now click New and type "D:\Python\"(for my example) in the new row. Click okay.

This sets the python's path and now close all cmd sessions and in a new command prompt enter Python and the session opens.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can install Python on drive D .
This site may helps you for installation of Python:
https://realpython.com/installing-python/