# Cannot find pip on PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, python, pip, anaconda

I am trying to install a package for python and I'm following the ["installing packages"](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/) on the python documentation in order to do so.

First it asks me to check that I have python on my computer. I'm supposed to type `python --version` on the Windows PowerShell to do this. But since I downloaded python through Anaconda, I luckily found out I needed to type a directory on top of that, like so:

[image]

So the next step is to check if I have `pip` installed, and I'm supposed to type `pip --version` and as you can imagine I get this:

[image]

Adding a directory like I did for `python` does not solve this problem. How can I check that pip is installed in my computer if I installed python through Anaconda?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add Python to the Windows PATH?](https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-windows-path)

Answer (score 1):

It is usually inside the `site-packages` folder.
This is my output:

```
PS C:\Users\NFR> pip --version
pip 19.0.3 from c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
```

So, in your case, it should be inside `..\Anaconda3\python\lib\site-packages`

Answer (score 0):

You have to tick the box: "Add Python 3.9 to PATH" when installing python.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE2P3.png)